# Bypassing role based AAD access in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac

We have a multi tenant ASP.NET MVC application *.foo.com hosted in Azure. We also have setup approles for this. Here is what I want to achieve:

1. Allow users from external tenants to login as long as they are assigned a role defined by us.
2. Allow all employees of 'foo' to login irrespective of role assigned, as we don't want to assign every single person a role.

Does anyone know if the requirements above can be met using a single aad app?
 Only other option I can think of is having 2 aad apps where first one will be a multitenant app for external users and role based while second one will be a single tenant app for internal users.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one multi tenant app to achieve your two requirements .

Requirement 1 : After user from a different tenant consent the application ,a representation of the application called a service principal is created in the user’s tenant ,you would find the provisioned application under `Enterprise applications` . Then admin could assign role to users in external tenant :
click on the `Users` tab. Select any userand assign the user to an Application Role.

Requirement 2 : If you set `User assignment required?` setting to false , then anyone in current tenant could access the application by default . You could find the setting in `Enterprise applications`-->Your application -->`Properties` .

Comment: Unfortunately, the directions in Requirement 2 don't work for me. I have already set the User assignment required to false. But when I run the app I get the following error: 'AADSTS50105: The signed in user is not assigned to a role for the application. And interestingly, if I login from another tenant, the app works fine. Does the 'User assignment required?' work for both internal and external tenants?

Comment: No , application in  internal and external tenants has its own setting(independent setting) . Admin should set the `User assignment required` of that application in his tenant . So you can set `User assignment required` to false , and admins in other tenants should set the value base on requirement .

Comment: Hmm. So does this mean, if the admin of external tenants set 'User assignment required' to false, all employees from those tenants can login to my app? Is there a way to block users from other tenants who do not have any role set?

Comment: If the app is registered in tenant A , only users in tenant A could access the resources in tenant A , users can't access resources in tenant B . If the admin of external tenants set 'User assignment required' to false , then in external tenants ,users in those tenants could access the applications in his tenant .

Comment: For exmaple , a multi-tenant application  has permission users.read , in current tenant , after consent , user could login that application and get current tenant's users information . In tenant B , after consent , application (service principle ) is registered  in tenant B , users in tenant B can login the application and get tenant B's users information . But users can't get users information in tenant A .  Admin of each tenant need to set `'User assignment required` base on requirement (If all of my tenant users can access application and get resources of my tenant ?).

Comment: If I understand correctly, app roles should not be used to block users from signing in to an app. Instead they should ideally be used in code to allow users to perform certain actions based on their roles. Also, the logic to allow only specific tenants can be present in the 'IssuerValidator' for OpenIdConnect. Correct?

Comment: Is there a way to block existing live/outlook.com users to login through the multi tenant AAD app? Thanks for the detailed explanation. This helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151660/discussion-between-agenthunt-and-nan-yu).